# Using variables instead of a long statement?

Tags: java

I am facing a confusion while working with objects. I searched google but couldn't find actual words to search for. The question is:

I am working with objects which consist some other object. For example:

```
 public void mapObjects(A a, B b) {
    a.setWeight(BigDecimal.valueOf(b.getWeight));
    //Now my doubt lies here
    if (a.getCharges.getDiscounts.getDiscountList != null) {
      for(int i = 0; i < a.getCharges.getDiscounts.getDiscountList.size(); i++){
          b.getList().get(0).setDiscountValue(a.getCharges.getDiscounts.getDiscountList.get(i).getValue());
          b.getList().get(0).setDiscountName(a.getCharges.getDiscounts.getDiscountList.get(i).getValue);
      }
    }

}
```

The above code is just an example. The project in which I am working uses similar type of coding style. The usage of `a.getCharges.getDiscounts.getDiscountList()` kind of code always bugs me. Because I am again and again calling the same statement.

When I asked a senior why dont we save this statement into a simple List<> variable. He told me that it will use extra references which will increase overhead. Can using a variable be that much overhead than calling getters again and again?

Comment: Your "senior" is totally bonkers.

Comment: This makes me want to throw up....

Comment: That's what the problem is. Now our code is totally a pile of long statements. And we could not help it as it's to much to change.

Comment: Please, at least make an adapter to call `b.set(index, value)`.

Comment: Please ask your "senior" to get a refresher course on Java if he has worked on it and if not then enroll for a basic Java course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Java exchanges references not actual object, if you take a local variable it will just add a reference variable entry in stack frame.

- This memory would be very less, almost negligible
- This memory will be released once the method is completed because this will be local to the method

Despite that, you can gain significant performance gains if you use local variables. You are extracting same information within loop multiple times.

1. `a.getCharges.getDiscounts.getDiscountList.size()` is called multiple times. It should be a local variable.
2. `b.getList().get(0)` is being called multiple times. It should be a local variable.
3. `a.getCharges.getDiscounts.getDiscountList` is called multiple times. It should be a local variable.

Changing these to local variables would results in good performance gains, because unnecessary method calls would be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Point your senior to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops). If it works for limited resources on Android, I guess the technique of storing in local variables everything used in a for cycle is actually beneficial for performance anywhere.

In the excerpt below, note that we aren't even speaking about the overhead introduced by calling the (virtual) `list.size()` method, only storing the `array.length` as a local variable produces notable differences in performance.

```
public void zero() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length; ++i) {
        sum += mArray[i].mSplat;
    }
}

public void one() {
    int sum = 0;
    Foo[] localArray = mArray;
    int len = localArray.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        sum += localArray[i].mSplat;
    }
}

public void two() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Foo a : mArray) {
        sum += a.mSplat;
    }
}
```

> zero() is slowest, because the JIT can't yet optimize away the cost of getting the array length once for every iteration through the loop.
>
> one() is faster. It pulls everything out into local variables, avoiding the lookups. Only the array length offers a performance benefit.
>
> two() is fastest for devices without a JIT, and indistinguishable from one() for devices with a JIT. It uses the enhanced for loop syntax introduced in version 1.5 of the Java programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `discountList` field never null - ie initialized to an empty list - and iterate over it. Something like:

```
for (Discount discount : a.getCharges().getDiscounts().getDiscountList()) {
    b.getList().get(0).setDiscountValue(discount.getValue());
    b.getList().get(0).setDiscountName(discount.getName());
}
```

Your "senior" may need to do some research. The "performance impact" of doing this is a few bytes per object and a few microseconds per access. If he's really hung up about memory, initialise it with a LinkedList, which has almost no memory footprint.

Comment: Didn't get the last line.

Comment: @Amber most people use ArrayLists without thinking. ArrayLists are initialized with a backing array of size 16, so 17 memory locations are burned. But LinkedLists don't allocate any memory for elements when initialized, so if they're usually empty (or nearly empty) they use less memory than ArrayLists (even though they use more memory per element when they grow).

Answer (score 0):

In Java  a variable `V` pointing to an object instance `O` is simply a numeric value pointing to a memory location where the object's data is stored.

When we assign `V`to another variable `V1` all that happens is that `V1` now points to the same memory location where data for `O` is stored. This means that **new memory** is not allocated when you do simple assignment unlike C++ code where the `=` operator can be be overloaded to do a deep-copy in which case new memory is actually allocated. Illustrating with an example below

Consider a class like below

```
class Foo {

   private List<String> barList = new ArrayList<>();

   //class methods...

  //getter for the list
  List<String> getBarList() {
      return this.barList;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Foo f = new Foo()
   //the below lien will print 0 since there is no bar string added
   System.out.println("Bar list size: " + f.getBarList().size());

  // add a bar string. Observe here that I am simply getting the list 
  // and adding - similar to how your code is currently structured
  f.getBarList().add("SomeString");
  //now get a reference to the list and store it in a variable. 
  // Below anotherList only points to the same memory location 
  // where the original bar list is present. No new memory is allocated.
  List<String> anotherList = f.getBarList();
  //print the content of bar list and another list. Both will be same
  for(String s : f.getBarList()) {
     System.out.println(s);
  }
  for(String s: anotherList) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }

  //add a new bar string using the reference variable
  anotherList.add("Another string");
  //print the content of bar list and another list. Both will be same. If anotherList had separate memory allocated to it then the new string added would be only seen when we print the content of anotherList and not when we print the content of f.getBarList(). This proves that references are only some numeric addresses that point to locations of the object on heap.
  for(String s : f.getBarList()) {
     System.out.println(s);
  }
  for(String s: anotherList) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add an explanation how this answers the question, as it stands, it just looks like a code drop with a zero-information introduction.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the feedback - I have updated the answer with some preliminary introduction